# Additional alert shows up using AppAuth to authenticate in swift4

Tags: openid, ios11, swift4, appauth

I am using `AppAuth` 0.90.0 for authentication using an external authentication server where a user can log in so the app receives appropriate authentication tokens. Since recently (after upgrade to swift 4) I get the following alert before I get sent to the authentication server:

> "App Name" Wants to Use "externalAuthentication.com" to Sign in"
>
> This allows the app and website to share information about you.

Has someone experienced the same issue and/or has a solution so the user does not need to press continue each time a request to that server is made?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well as it's doing on an app I also am working on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is happening because AppAuth uses `SFAuthenticationSession` by default instead of `SFSafariViewController` on iOS11. There is unfortunately nothing we can do at the moment to either change or remove these alerts when using `SFAuthenticationSession`. You can follow this [Github thread](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/120) that discusses the issues and changes when using AppAuth on iOS11.