# Facebook / Google Login with Fireboard show always alert

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, google-signin

I'm trying to use Facebook and Google login through Firebase for user management.

***P.S. I Follow the Firebase Documentation***

Everything works well for now but I have a problem ...

**1. I do not understand why every time I push the facebbok login button or the google login button I see this Alert ...**

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to show the alert only once? what should it always show?

**2. We come to the second problem. Each time my app reaches the page where the user chooses to login, the same alert appears that I showed you at the top of the photo ... In this case, the user has not yet selected any login method Google's alert should not immediately appear.**

Can you help me with this?

This is my code from App Delegate where is Google button and Facebook set

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@import Firebase;
@import GoogleSignIn;
@import FBSDKCoreKit;

@interface AppDelegate () <GIDSignInDelegate>

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [FIRApp configure];

    // GOOGLE
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = [FIRApp defaultApp].options.clientID;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;

    // FACEBOOK
    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(nonnull UIApplication *)application openURL:(nonnull NSURL *)url options:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options {

    // FACEBOOK
    BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];

    //GOOGLE
     [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];

    return handled;
}

// GOOGLE GIDSignInDelegate
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {

    if (error == nil) {
        GIDAuthentication *authentication = user.authentication;
        FIRAuthCredential *credential = [FIRGoogleAuthProvider credentialWithIDToken:authentication.idToken accessToken:authentication.accessToken];

        [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential completion:^(FIRUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Nessun account registrato su FireBase da Google errore: %@", error);

                NSLog(@"%@", credential);
                return ;
            }
            NSLog(@"Registrazione Completata");
        }];

    } else NSLog(@"LOGIN GOOGLE ERRORE %@", error);

}
```

This is my viewController with facebook button

```
#import "KPValidation.h"
@import Firebase;
@import GoogleSignIn;
@import FBSDKLoginKit;
@import FBSDKCoreKit;

@interface KPValidation () <GIDSignInUIDelegate, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate>

@end

@implementation KPValidation

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setupGoogleButton];
    [self setupFacebookButton];
}

-(void)setupFacebookButton {
    FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginButton.delegate = self;
    loginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"email", @"public_profile"];
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];

    [loginButton.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor constant:-100].active = YES;
    [loginButton.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [loginButton.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor].active = YES;
    [loginButton.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:50].active = YES;
}

- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error {

    FIRAuthCredential *credential = [FIRFacebookAuthProvider credentialWithAccessToken:[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString];

     [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // ...
            return;

        }
        // User successfully signed in. Get user data from the FIRUser object
        // ...

         NSLog(@"%@", user.email);
       //  [self showEmail];

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Question 1: You should take a look at this  [Additional alert shows up using AppAuth to authenticate in swift4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666795/additional-alert-shows-up-using-appauth-to-authenticate-in-swift4)
- Question 2: I think in your `application:openURL:options:` method, you should check input url. If it's Facebook url, use `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` else use `GIDSignIn`.

  ```
  - (BOOL)application:(nonnull UIApplication *)application openURL:(nonnull NSURL *)url options:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options {

    if (/*url is Facebook url*/) {
      return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
    } else {
      return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
    }
  }
  ```